# check for only selected element if that has text in it but not its child

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to check if a selected element have text inside it , the problem is when i am trying to checking value by `innerText` its also returning values from child which is why boolean function is returning true but what i am expecting to do is just verify one element and avoiding child's i hope i have exlpained it correct so what can be a proper way to achive this

```js
const main = document.querySelector(".main")
const first = main.querySelector(".selected")
const second = main.querySelector(".another")
const third = main.querySelector(".another-one")

function hasText(el){
  return el.innerText != ""
}
console.log(hasText(first),hasText(second),hasText(third)) // true true true expected result is = [true false,true]
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="selected">
        i have text inside me
    </div>
    <div class="another">
        <div class="child">i am inside a child</div>
    </div>
    <div class="another-one">
        i am inside another one
        <div class="child">i am inside a child</div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Both `selected` and `child` are child elements of `main`. `selected` and `child` are _sibling_ elements.

Comment: When I run your code snippet it returns [true,true] which is the expected result.  It does not return [true, false] as stated in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options to achieve your goal. You could just check if `el` has children elements and in case `.children.length > 0` just consider it as a text container and measure its `innerText` length.

But in case those parent elements are also supposed to optionally contain both children elements and text, you should check every single childNode of theirs, verify if that's a text portion and consider that text to be part of parent content.Those nodes will be text portions sparse in between legit children elements.

There's also the `textContent` property of Node that could give you an information similar to that returned by my function `grabPureTextContent` but there are caveats that I preferred to cut off implementing my own logic.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Here's a demo adding such function to your code and using its logic to determine if a given element has text content or not.

I added a third case (.special) showing what happens when there's mixed content.

```js
const main = document.querySelector(".main")
const first = main.querySelector(".selected")
const second = main.querySelector(".another")
const third = main.querySelector(".special")

/*
Returns the pure text content defined in el
looping through its childNodes and concatenating content,
(if child is text only) before returning the whole string.

There's also the option to use textContent property of Node
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent
But here the algorithm is more clear on what's going on
*/
function grabPureTextContent(el){
  let content = '';
  for(childText of el.childNodes){
    if (childText.constructor.name == 'Text'){    
      content += childText.nodeValue.trim();
    }
  }
  return content;
}

function hasText(el){      
  if (grabPureTextContent(el).length > 0)
    return true;
  return false;
}

console.log(hasText(third)) //=> true
console.log(hasText(second)) //=> false
console.log(hasText(third)) //=> true
```

```css
.main > div {
  border: solid 1px gray;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.container {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.child {
  background: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="container selected">
        i have text inside me
    </div>
    <div class="container another">
        <div class="child">i am inside a child</div>
    </div>
    <!-- special case having both children and text -->
    <div class="container special">    
        <div class="child">i am inside a child</div>  
        TEXT HERE after child
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for your information, using regex here is semantically wrong. There are conditions that could break the rule and anyway it's a very inefficient approach.

Comment: I tried to fix it but and see that is would have some cases which breaks the rules. Thanks for hint! :-)

Comment: Good answer because it handles the non-obvious cases where text follows a child node or the text is only whitespace. +1

Comment: by the way @MaikLowrey I sounded maybe too aggressive. Your regex solution isn't that bad because somehow tried to address the problem and achieved some positive result. I just meant to say why it would be better to adopt a more structured approach in this case because you already have such information in the dom without relying on regular expressions.

Comment: Remember that using regex to parse html is very wrong because it brings to unwanted outcomes and it's impossible to do it correctly. Consider always the opportunity to parse a raw html using a real parser and fetching data from its returned tree. @Yogi yes I did my best to correctly cover all those cases and I relied on trim() to sanitize the input before collecting text content. It should correctly address any case but I can't be totally sure by design because the input requirement isn't perfectly clear about that

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Null problemo :-). I didn't take your answer negatively or aggressively. On the contrary, I am glad when people talk about answers and comment. Thanks for your feedback! By the way. I tried the regex solution for a few minutes because it didn't give me any peace. It was and is not easy. I probably won't update my answer, because it would indeed be a solution that contains many side effects.

Answer (score 1):

I would test if some tags inside the string. If not you can use your check if is empty.

```js
const main = document.querySelector(".main")
const first = main.querySelector(".selected")
const second = main.querySelector(".another")
const third = main.querySelector(".another2")

function hasText(el) {    
  const pattern = /<.*>.*<\/.*>/;
  return pattern.test(el.innerHTML) ? false : (el.innerText != "");  
}
console.log(hasText(first),hasText(second), hasText(third)) // true true expected result is = [true false true]
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="selected">
        i have text inside me
    </div>
    <div class="another">
        <div class="child">i am inside a child</div>
    </div>
      <div class="another2">
        i am inside a child
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your third html is wrong

Comment: @AmirRahman I see now. I will fix it but i think that Diego De Vita approach is better! Thank you for the nice question!